# Spring filter bypassed when a REST endpoint returns a Json stream

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have an endpoint which return a `ResponseBodyEmitter`:

```
@GetMapping("/foo/stream")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseBodyEmitter> getFoos() {
    ResponseBodyEmitter rbe = new ResponseBodyEmitter();
    executor.execute(() -> {
        try {
                rbe.send(foo1);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                rbe.send(foo2);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                rbe.send(foo3);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            rbe.complete();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            rbe.completeWithError(ex);
        }
    });
    return ResponseEntity.ok(rbe);
}
```

A custom filter (`FooValidationFilter`) is created to perform checks on foo's object when this endpoint is called:

```
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FooValidationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestToCache = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseToUse = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);

        filterChain.doFilter(request, responseToUse);

        if (!responseToUse.isCommitted() &&
                responseToUse.getStatus() >= 200 && responseToUse.getStatus() < 300 &&
                HttpMethod.GET.matches(request.getMethod())) {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(responseToUse.getContentInputStream());
            String fooField;
            do {
                fooField = scanner.findWithinHorizon(REGEX, 0); 
                // perform some checks
            } while (fooField != null);
        }

        if (requestToCache.isAsyncStarted()) {
            requestToCache.getAsyncContext().addListener(new AsyncListener() {
                public void onComplete(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
                    responseToUse.copyBodyToResponse();
                }

                public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
                }

                public void onError(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
                }

                public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
                }
            });
        } else {
            responseToUse.copyBodyToResponse();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilterAsyncDispatch() {
        return false;
    }
```

**Note:**

1. In debug mode, the `FooValidationFilter` is called after each `ResponseBodyEmitter.send()`.
2. In normal mode, the `FooValidationFilter` is invoked only one time. So, the checks on some Foo objects will be bypassed.

Am I missing something which is causing this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Spring Docs for OncePerFilterRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html) :

> It says that this filter base class aims to guarantee a single
> execution per request dispatch, on any servlet container.

But in some case, it can happen that the other servlets are also using the same filter due to that it can be called multiple times.

Now, coming to your issue. I suspect the issue is with the way you are debugging `ExecutorService` that is making the `FooValidationFilter` to be called multiple times in debug mode and not in normal mode.

Debugging `ExecutorService` is difficult sometimes because in debug mode, its execution can't be predicted. So, you don't think that if it's called multiple times in debug mode, then it will be called multiple times in normal mode.

---

I tried to reproduce with the code that you have provided. I have used STS Eclipse IDE to debug the scenario. The filter is called for two times in normal mode.

- Normal Mode :

Controller logic :

```
@RestController
public class Resource {

    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    @GetMapping("/foo/stream")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseBodyEmitter> handleRbe() {
        ResponseBodyEmitter emitter = new ResponseBodyEmitter();
        executor.execute(() -> {
            try {
                emitter.send("a");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                emitter.send("b");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                emitter.send("c");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                emitter.complete();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                emitter.completeWithError(ex);
            }
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseBodyEmitter>(emitter, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Added logger into your existing filter :

```
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class ValidationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        log.info("Inside Filter");
        
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestToCache = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseToUse = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);

        filterChain.doFilter(request, responseToUse);

        if (!responseToUse.isCommitted() &&
                responseToUse.getStatus() >= 200 && responseToUse.getStatus() < 300 &&
                HttpMethod.GET.matches(request.getMethod())) {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(responseToUse.getContentInputStream());
//            String fooField;
//            do {
//                fooField = scanner.findWithinHorizon("", 0); 
//                // perform some checks
//            } while (fooField != null);
        }

        if (requestToCache.isAsyncStarted()) {
            requestToCache.getAsyncContext().addListener(new AsyncListener() {
                public void onComplete(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
                    responseToUse.copyBodyToResponse();
                }

                public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
                }

                public void onError(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
                }

                public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
                }
            });
        } else {
            responseToUse.copyBodyToResponse();
        }
        log.info("End Filter");
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilterAsyncDispatch() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Note:** You also need to add `@Component` in your filter which was missing.

Postman request :

[image]

Server logs in normal mode to prove that it's called multiple times :

[image]

---

- Debug Mode steps to prove that it got called two times:

The request came to the filter first.

[image]

The request came to the controller :

[image]

The response comes back from controller and the filter check if the isAsyncStarted() is true. In this case, it returns true which means async context started.

[image]

It comes to the same line again -> `filterChain.doFilter(request, responseToUse);`

[image]

Server Log at this point in debug mode :

[image]

The response comes back from controller and the filter check if the isAsyncStarted() is true. In this case, it returns false and the async context is skipped.

Server log at the end :

[image]

---

Postman response :

[image]

Update : As per Spring's [ResponseBodyEmitter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseBodyEmitter.html#complete--) Docs, it states that :

> Write the given object to the response.
>
> If any exception occurs a dispatch is made back to the app server
> where Spring MVC will pass the exception through its exception
> handling mechanism.
>
> Note: if the send fails with an IOException, you do not need to call
> completeWithError(Throwable) in order to clean up. Instead the Servlet
> container creates a notification that results in a dispatch where
> Spring MVC invokes exception resolvers and completes processing.

In simple words :

> `send()` method only writes to the response. It doesn't mean that it
> will make dispatch to filter/interceptor on send() method call. The
> send method only combines all the individual send data and append it
> to the response.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer :) Since we're on asynchronous context, the normal behavior I'm expecting is : on each send call the filter is accessed.

Comment: @Katy I tried to use the code that you have provided. In both, debug mode and normal mode, the filter is called multiple times. I'm updating my answer. Please verify.

Comment: @Katy the normal behavior that you are expecting is : on each send call the filter is accessed -> is not possible to achieve. The filter are never meant to be used in that way.

Comment: Thank you for your attention to the question, what I know is `ResponseBodyEmitter.send()` https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseBodyEmitter.html
enables to send response in several part. 
Hence, each response part (after `send()` call) should be intercepted separately by the filter. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Katy I don't think you are missing anything. First of all, doc says that send() method only writes to the response. It doesn't mean that it will make dispatch to filter/interceptor on send() method call. The send method only combines all the individual send data and append it to the response.

Comment: @Katy I can suggest that you can write your own custom dynamic proxy for ResponseBodyEmitter and give custom implementation instead of depending on predefined logic.